# JQuery Autocomplete select doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

Hy

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    selectFirst: true,
    select: function (a, b) {
        $(this).val(b.item.value);
        $("#tag_form").submit();
    }
  }).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13){
     $("#tag_form").submit();
    }
 })
 });
```

The keydown function for Enter is working cool, but the select does not, and i do not know why. I just want, when i click on an item, then submit my form with id tag_form.

Please help, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're in the **this** context of select method. You should find for input id like `$('#inputId').val('//blah')`;

```
select: function (a, b) {
        $(this).val(b.item.value); // $(this) represent select method
        $("#tag_form").submit();
    }
```

I hope this will help You. Feel free to ask!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Bah/)**

Comment: My problem is with this part : `$("#tag_form").submit();`
Do you know what is wrong with this ? Or I just dont understand your answer well.

Comment: Hey, the problem you have is in a line that you dont't post it here. I make a demo to show you that everything works good if you use correct id's. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/C8Bah/

Comment: I using this under wordpress, and it doesnt work for me. I'm still trying.

Comment: Verify the browser console. You could do that easy in mozilla and chrome, try to find if you have a javascript error.

Comment: Do not have error, but i noticed the `select: function (a,b){...}` necer running, i put here an alert() and i didnt see it, but in your demo code it works.

Comment: autocomplete.php should respond with json